# Search within a search in SOLR

Tags: solr, search-engine

Is it possible to search within a previous hit list in SOLR? E.g. first search "hello", then on the result list, user wants to search records containing "world". Is it the same thing as searching *hello AND world*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it the same thing as searching hello AND world?

I believe so.

Alternately, you can use a [filter query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq), e.g. `?q=hello&fq=world`

This probably isn't the right solution in the "Hello world" case, but it may be an interesting example nonetheless.

Answer (score 4):

Using filter query is a good solution. Only difference is in scoring documents, whatever is used in filter query is not used in scoring.

In

```
?q=hello&fq=world
```

only *hello* is scored.

However in

```
?q=hello+AND+world
```

both words are scored

Comment: thank you for the additional information on Filter Query, much appreciated!